# Listing instances in Azure with python SDK

Tags: python, azure

I am looking for examples for listing instances in Azure with help of python SDK,
I went through the docs available for python SDK but wasn't able to get anything out of it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Prince

Comment: instances of what?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage

Comment: Can you give a ore specific type of resource instance you want to list?

Comment: I need to list VM instances created from custom images.